# How to get rid of eval in subclass appending to superclass instance list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class

I am using eval to run a generated string to append the newly created EggOrder instance to the list of the correct instance of the DailyOrders class. The day provided by EggOrder is used to used to append to the correct instance. This relies on eval and the variable name of the DailyOrders instance and so it would be great to get this removed. I know there must be a better way.

```
class DailyOrders:

    PRICE_PER_DOZEN = 6.5

    def __init__(self, day):
        self.orders = []
        self.day = day

    def total_eggs(self):
        total_eggs = 0
        for order in self.orders:
            total_eggs += order.eggs
        return total_eggs

    def show_report(self):
        if self.total_eggs() < 0:
            print("No Orders")
        else:
            print(f"Summary:\nTotal Eggs Ordered: {self.total_eggs()}")
            print(f"Average Eggs Per Customer: {self.total_eggs() / len(self.orders):.0f}\n*********")


class EggOrder():

    def __init__(self, eggs=0, name="", day=""):
        if not name:
            self.new_order()
        else:
            self.name = name
            self.eggs = eggs
            self.day = day

        eval(f"{self.day.lower()}.orders.append(self)")

    def new_order(self):
        self.name = string_checker("Name: ")
        self.eggs = num_checker("Number of Eggs: ")
        self.day = string_checker("Date: ")

    def get_dozens(self):
        if self.eggs % 12 != 0:
            dozens = int(math.ceil(self.eggs / 12))
        else:
            dozens = self.eggs / 12
        return dozens

    def show_order(self):

        print(f"{self.name} ordered {self.eggs} eggs. The price is ${self.get_dozens() * DailyOrders.PRICE_PER_DOZEN}.")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    friday = DailyOrders("Friday")
    friday_order = EggOrder(12, "Someone", "Friday")
    friday_order.show_order()
    friday.show_report()

    saturday = DailyOrders("Saturday")
    saturday_order = EggOrder(19, "Something", "Saturday")
    saturday_order = EggOrder(27, "Alex Stiles", "Saturday")
    saturday.show_report()
```

- DailyOrders isn't actually a superclass (it was in a earlier version), it acts like one and I suspect the answer might have some inheritance.

Comment: Use a dictionary to store data by key.

Comment: I don't know what that means. Please elaborate. Edit: spelling

Comment: You know about [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) in Python?

Comment: I know what they are, I don't know how I could apply them to my situation?

Comment: All your days should resist in one dictionary with the days' names as keys. As it is now you would also have namespace troubles. A dictionary can prevent that.

Comment: Can you answer the question providing an implementation? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I told you what to do. Try to implement it and tell us when you get stuck!

Comment: So you are suggesting that I put the days as keys with the objects as values? I would implement your feedback if I knew what was being suggested. I really have no idea.

Comment: Create a dictionary called `day_dict`. Replace `friday` with `day_dict['friday']`. Then you can use `day_dict[self.day.lower()].orders.append(self)`.